# Symfony2 / Doctrine model join single table to multiple other tables by related ID and type

Tags: php, database-design, symfony, model, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to work out the model for a fairly simple application, but I haven't been able to find good information regarding my idea for dealing with user comments. I was thinking that I could have a Comment table, with "related ID" and "related type" fields. These fields would be the composite foreign key back to whatever other table I wanted to link to. For example, you could leave a comment about a User, or a Location, or really any other entity. Is this kind of design possible in Symfony2/Doctrine? If so, is there a good example to reference somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

You'll need to use a discriminator field using **Single Table Inheritance** or **Class Table Inheritance**

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! I wasn't sure what keywords to search on... This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The link is not working is there any chance for update?